# FILE(XLSX) CONTENT AS EMAIL BODY IN TABLE FORMAT IN INFORMATICA

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am having tgt file as excel.I need to send email with Body as file content in table format.
How can we acheive this.

Comment: you need to create a email with html body.

Comment: Can you provide me sample

Comment: can you please give detailed information